# When a key on the keybaord is pressed in vb.net to load a form

Tags: vb.net

Recently i created a form and i want when the user presses f8 to load the private sub. i ve tried different methods but after the user enters data on the texboxes the function is not working
Here is some code :

```
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.F8 Then
         vnesiartikal()
    End If
```

The vnesiartikal() is used to enter a product in the database but if the button insert is selected the f8 opiton works but when the user insets the data in the textboxes the function is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the form's property of [KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) to **True**.
[image: Form's KeyPreview property]

Comment: how do i do that ? Thanks

Comment: I'd start by reading the linked documentation that explains how to do it, including code examples... *Edit* Or @Raw N could be kind enough to give you a screenshot

Comment: one more question how do i diselect a combobox thanks